# assign mouse event listener with loop to 10 movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, event-listener

I am trying to loop through my 10 "bomb" movieclips and assign an eventlistener that calls the same function but passes the current movieclips name. the "bomb" movieclip names are incremented.

Below is my try

```
 var i:number;
    i=0;
    while (i <= 10){
    var current_bomb:Movieclip = (movingbomb_+i);

       current_bomb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, function updateBomb(current_bomb));

    i++
    }

    function updateBomb(currentBomb):void{

        currentBomb.gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, but not quite. Also, using a `for` loop is a much better idea here. With those changes, the code should look something like this:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var currentBomb:MovieClip = this["movingbomb_" + i];
    currentBomb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, function (evt:MouseEvent):void { updateBomb(currentBomb); });
}

function updateBomb(currentBomb:MovieClip):void {
    currentBomb.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

Here's how this works.

1. The `for` loop simplifies all your `while` looping code into a single statement for efficiency.
2. We then select the current bomb using array-bracket selection syntax. To do this, you use `this[name]`, where `name` is a string. The string we use will be "movingbomb_" with `i` tacked on to the end.
3. Finally, we create a unique anonymous function for each new event listener which redirects the mouse event to your `updateBomb` function and passes the `currentBomb` object.

Comment: this is exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks for your help. +1 and checked.